# In ggplot2, how to change the legend labels but leave the colors unchanged?

Tags: r, ggplot2

Given following ggplot diagram,

```
p <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg, wt)) + geom_point(aes(colour = factor(cyl)))
```

If I want to change the labels of the legends, I can do the following:

```
p + scale_color_manual(labels = c("X", "Y", "Z"), values = 1:3)
```

But what should I do if I want to change the labels only and leave the colors unchanged? I've tried using the following formula:

```
p + scale_color_manual(labels = c("X", "Y", "Z"))
```

And it gives an error, saying: `Error in f(...) : argument "values" is missing, with no default`.

Of course, I can achieve this by setting the factor `cyl`:

```
mtcars$cyl = as.factor(mtcars$cyl, labels = c("X", "Y", "Z"))
ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg, wt)) + geom_point(aes(colour = factor(cyl)))
```

But, I wondering whether it is possible to achieve this in `scale_color_manual` or in some other ways.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about `scale_color_discrete`

```
p + scale_color_discrete(labels=letters[1:3])
```